# Angular Universal combined multiple applications

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal, subproject

I have a project in Angular Universal(Combined multiple applications) which contain subproject.
After server side rendering my subprojects everything works clear, except of `<app-root></app-root>` which came form general module, but I want for every subproject have its   `<app-root></app-root>`. Who faced this issue before.

Comment: Did u get any solution ?

Comment: I created One library an import that library via package json in all projects, that was solution for my problem, but steel I can not create sub projects.

Comment: Ok, I am looking for something like this. I'll post an answer, if I find any. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Angular CLI supports multiple applications within one workspace.

To create another app you can use the following command:

```
ng generate application my-other-app
```

The new application will be generated inside projects/my-other-app.

Now we can serve, build etc. both the apps by passing the project name with the commands:

```
ng serve my-other-app
```

You can also create libraries, which is detailed in [Create a library](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library).

Comment: Thank you for response, but my problem that in generated submodules I can not use app-root for every submodule, I want to remind I used angular universal and code rendered in server side , that's my problem